# SQL Server date diff for rows with certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a table named `Call` and another named `CallLog`. `CallLog` links to a `CallLogType`

```
CallId       AgentId
---------------------
1            123       
2            765
3            134
4            134          
5            134
```

---

```
CallLogId    CallId   Time                      LogType
---------------------------------------------------------------
1            1        2017-04-05 17:38:00       1 (InProgress)
2            1        2017-04-05 17:40:00       2 (OnHold)
3            1        2017-04-05 17:45:00       1 (InProgress)
4            1        2017-04-05 17:48:00       3 (Completed)
```

---

```
CallLogTypeId      Description
--------------------------------
1                  InProgress
2                  OnHold
3                  Completed
```

I need to write a query that, given an AgentId, finds their actual talk time for the day. 
One part I'm having trouble with is the fact the query needs to ignore the 'OnHold' state in the above example.

I should be able to pass in UserId 123 (they're on Call #1), and have it return a total time of 5 minutes for the sample data 
(2 minutes in progress, ignore the 5 minutes on hold and then 3 minutes more in progress).

I'm struggling to find the best approach to solve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is much more easily solved in the programming language of your choice.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? Please edit the question and add a corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about this one for a while, but came back to it and thought I should post an answer of some sort!

I've come up with a (likely less than ideal) query that seems to do the trick and returns the right results for the schema in the original question:

```
DECLARE @InProgress INT = 1
DECLARE @OnHold INT = 2
DECLARE @Completed INT = 3
DECLARE @AgentId INT = 123
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2017-07-11'

SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, LogJoin.Time, LogJoin.NextLogTime))
FROM Call C
    INNER JOIN
    (
       SELECT
          CL.CallId,
          CL.LogType,
          CL.Time,
          LEAD(CL.LogType, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY CL.CallId ORDER BY CL.CallLogId ASC) AS NextLogType,
          LEAD(CL.Time, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY CL.CallId ORDER BY CL.CallLogId ASC) AS NextLogTime
       FROM CallLog CL
          INNER JOIN Call C ON C.CallId = CL.CallId
       WHERE C.AgentId = @AgentId AND @Date = CAST(CL.Time AS DATE)
    ) LogJoin ON LogJoin.CallId = C.CallId AND LogJoin.LogType <> @OnHold
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the *LAG* function to get the date of the next record to be able to calculate the amount of time consumed in each status. Afterwards I would filter the *OnHold* status. Note that the query will give all the calls for the user with the ID stated in the parameter *:theFilterValue* with the time consumed.

```
select c.CallId,
       sum(datediff(minute, cl.time, lag(cl.time) over (order by cl.time))) as totalMinutes
  from CallLog cl
       inner join Call c on cl.CallId = c.CallId
 where cl.LogTypeId <> 2 -- OnHold
       and c.AgentId = :theFilterValue
       and lag(cl.time) over (order by cl.time) is not null
group by 
       c.AgentId,
       c.CallId
```

Comment: I think this is likely a good solution. I neglected to mention that we're using SQL-Server, which doesn't seem to like how the lag function is being used in your sample. I'm going to try and rework it a tad and verify it does what we need!